# Using Watir-webdriver how to check the URL of a page

Tags: ruby, automation, watir, watir-webdriver

I am new to watir-webdriver automation, apologies if its a basic question of automation. But the thing is I am automating pagination of a website where the URL of the website changes as the user changes the page 
say the URL is www.example.co.uk/news which has pagination when the user clicks next button on the pagination the URL changes to www.example.co.uk/news?page=1

I want to check the URL at this point to see if the URL is correct.
But I can't really find a way to get the URL of the current page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`browser.url` will return url of the page, so to check if it is as expected, try something like this:

```
browser.url == "www.example.co.uk/news?page=1"
```

It will return true or false.